# Automatically turn off debug variable in production

Tags: javascript, debugging, production

Currently I'm trying to find a way to automatically switch my all mighty `debug = true` in production. I thought of things like the server-name or an IP-Whitelist where this switch wont happen. Because of the sandboxed nature of Javascript this is getting quite tight.

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: You can have two separate functions and call them in separate gulp tasks. For eg : gulp deploy-dev and gulp deploy-prod. Debug can be set to false in prod and true in dev.

Comment: Yeah, that would help. But its not that automatic as I wish it would be :P

Answer (score 1):

You could control debugging mode at run-time, by passing some information as argument in the URL. Inside your javascript code, you would set debug to false by default, unless the page URL (window.location) contains some expected parameter value.

The downside of this is that you keep your debug code in production, and the upside is that you have debugging capabilities in production as well.

Comment: Thats actually a nice approach. I'll play with it around a bit

Comment: We are currently using it in one of our applications. This allows us to not only set debug mode to true, but to configure multiple parameters at run-time, without having to deploy anything.